# Lookup object return null in trigger

Tags: apex, lookup, trigger

For all this time, what I understand that I can get through look up field object such as Owner Name directly without need to write query, but after writing this code, it seem like I understand it wrongly.

```
for (Opportunity opp : Trigger.new) {
      system.debug('Print this opp.Owner.CustomField1__c --' + opp.Owner.CustomField1__c);
 }
```

Owner is look up for User,it return null while I know it has value.I need clarification on this, is something wrong with my system debug or I need to manually write the query to retrieve owner details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can't get relationship fields in `trigger.new`. You have to query relationship fields

And owner field is populated by Salesforce. So ownerId field value you can get once data is committed to database. I believe you will get the ownerId in 
after trigger

```
for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Id, Owner.CustomField1__c 
                          FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: Trigger.new]) {
   system.debug('Print this opp.Owner.CustomField1__c --' + opp.Owner.CustomField1__c);
 }
```

Comment: Yes,I found this article.After and Before context also can make the difference.http://www.iterativelogic.com/salesforce-apex-trigger-best-practices/

Comment: Add this link because I think it also useful for future ref https://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/02/23/relationship-lookup-objects-in-triggers-are-null/